# A matrix polynomial equation when power goes to infinity.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A=\pmatrix{\frac2{10}&\frac3{10}\\\frac3{10}&\frac5{10}},\\B=\pmatrix{2&3\\4&5},\\XA+XA^2+XA^3+...=B$$ what is $X$?
I think it is kind of like the transition matrix, but the sum of each row is not 1. So how should I get started?

Comment: Polynomial of infinite degree isn't.

Comment: Isn't what? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix $A$ has eigenvalues of absolute value $< 1$, so the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A^n$ converges to $A(I-A)^{-1}$.

But please don't call it a "polynomial of infinite degree".

Comment: Great! Thank you! And sorry about the term, I am not very familiar with those in English curently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate the matrix power of A and evaluate the sum which has to converge against a Matrix $ S $. So consider $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty A^k=: S $.
Than you only have to solve $ X\cdot S=B $.